# How to negate this statement for a proof by contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

I want to try and construct a proof by contradiction but am having a hard time negating this statement.

The statement that I am working with is

> There are only a finite number of points accepted into the set and
>   this finite sequence converges to a stationary point.

So I want to prove this statement but want to do it with contradiction. How do I negate this statement to start the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negation of "The subject is suchathing and behaves suchlike" is

- "Either the subject is not suchathing, *or* does not behave suchlike"

> Either there is an infinite number of points accepted into the set, *or* the finite sequence does not converge to a stationary point.

Comment: So could I say "There are only a finite number of points accepted into the set and this finite sequence does not converge to a stationary point."

Comment: @RustyStatistician _No._ The statement in the answer is the negation of your theorem. The statement in your comment is a different statement, not equivalent to the negation of your theorem.